# (Redirecting https with wildcard (fiddler)

Tags: redirect, https, fiddler

I am trying to use fiddler to filter domains using the //custom rules section and using https redirection I am trying to use a wild card like this in the https redirect.

This is what's currently working

```
    // Redirect traffic, including HTTPS tunnels
    if (oSession.HTTPMethodIs("CONNECT") && (oSession.PathAndQuery == "pagead2.doubleclick.net:443")) { 
        oSession.PathAndQuery = "localhost"; 
    }

    if (oSession.HostnameIs("pagead2.doubleclick.net:443")) oSession.hostname = "localhost";
```

Below is what I want to do but isn't working

```
    // Redirect traffic, including HTTPS tunnels
    if (oSession.HTTPMethodIs("CONNECT") && (oSession.PathAndQuery == "*.doubleclick.net:443")) { 
        oSession.PathAndQuery = "localhost"; 
    }

    if (oSession.HostnameIs("*.doubleclick.net:443")) oSession.hostname = "localhost";
```

[The script is directly from fiddlers script page Exact Area of Tutorial on fiddlerbook.com](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mo4g5.png)

https://fiddlerbook.com/fiddler/dev/scriptsamples.asp

Any help is greatly appreciated I am looking to make this an adblock proxy.